# Error using eclipse oxygen windowbuilder on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: java, eclipse

I've installed swt windowdbuilder on eclipse oxygen but when I try yo use the design view I gent this error

```
 Designer [1.10.0.201712050731.201712061243]: No more handles
No more handles
```

And this is the stacktrace from the console

```
Eclipse:2785): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 3069 was not found when attempting to remove it
Gdk-Message: Unable to load sizing from the cursor theme
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4559)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4448)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4419)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Cursor.<init>(Cursor.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.wb.draw2d.ICursorConstants.<clinit>(ICursorConstants.java:98)
```

I tried  with the command 'ulimit -c unlimited '  and setting eclipse.ini from `Xmx1024m` to `Xmx2048m` but doesn't worked

Comment: try to use GTK2 instead of GTK3 using the following way to start Eclipse: `SWT_GTK3=0 ./eclipse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can try to use GTK2 instead of GTK3 using the following way to start Eclipse: `SWT_GTK3=0 ./eclipse`

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46341108